# Node.js : how to know if a value is in a collection of a MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

It must be a very simple question, but I can't find a way to do it...

I have a very basic MongoDB collection of documents, which I can represent in JSON format like this :

```
myDatabase.myCollection = {
  {hashkey: "hashkey1",
   data: "someData"
  },
  {hashkey: "hashkey2",
   data: "someData"
  },
  {hashkey: "hashkey3",
   data: "someData"
  }
}
```

Each hashkey value is unique.

Now, I want to write the following code in Node.js :

```
// I use npm mongodb, sounds good ?
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

// initiating connection to myDatabase...

var db = "my_database_I_just_connected_to";
var myCollection = db.collection('myCollection');

var newHashkey = "hashkeyX";

if ("newHashkey_is_already_in_myCollection") {
  doSomething();
} else {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

I am looking for a way to get the boolean "newHashkey_is_already_in_myCollection". Using my example database :

- if "hashkeyX" === "hashkey1" ------> true
- if "hashkeyX" === "hashkey5" ------> false

I must be blind, but I can't find an immediate function for this purpose. I have tried many ways using selectors, counting returned documents, trying to understand cursors vs objects... Won't do. My initial thought was :

```
if (myCollection.findOne({hashkey: "hashkeyX"}) === null) {
  doSomething();
} else {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

1) What is a good/best way to get such a boolean ?

2) [Optional :] Could you link me to some good explanations about such questions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findOne` is an async operation, you must use callback and check that object is exists there:

```
myCollection.findOne({hashkey: "hashkeyX"}, function(err, obj) {
  if (err) {
    // TODO: process error
  }
  if (obj) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
```

Comment: THAT would be logical. Being new to Node, I often make callback mistakes... What about the other answers, then ? Won't work ?

Comment: Check official node.js mongodb documentation it could help: https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/client/

Comment: Async is powerful, beautiful, and requires me to change the way I think... It works perfectly, and thanks for the link, I only had the npm mongodb readme... Thanks a lot !

Comment: Np:), Also I'm recommending you try to use `mongoose` ODM for working with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

If you could represent the data like this:

```
myDatabase.myCollection = {
  "hashkey1": {
   data: "someData"
  },
  "hashkey2": {
   data: "someData"
  },
  "hashkey2": {
   data: "someData"
  }
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
if (db.collection(newHashkey)) {
  doSomething();
} else {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand   ".myCollection(newHashkey)".  Is it supposed to work in Node.js / mongodb module ?

Comment: I did not write that the way I wanted to. I corrected it.